# Are there any preservation theorems for quotients of subalgebras?

Tags: universal-algebra

Let $X$ denote an algebraic structure. Then:

- Every subalgebra of $X$ satisfies each [quasi-identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiidentity) that is satisfied by $X$. In other words, taking subalgebras preserves quasi-identities.
- Every quotient of $X$ satisfies every existentially-quantified equation satisfied by $X$. In other words, taking quotients preserves existentially-quantified equations.

> **Question.** Aside from the fact that taking quotient of a subalgebra of $X$ preserves identities, does this process preserve any other kinds of statements?

Comment: As stated, this is misleading. Subalgebras preserve much more; exactly the universal sentences. On the other hand, the second bullet is wrong: quotients preserve positive sentences (so not every existential one; v.g. $\mathbb{Z}\models$ “there are at least $3$ elements”, but $\mathbb{Z}_2$ doesn't).

Comment: I think "positive universal" is the answer, but I don't think that these two words count as a good answer.

Comment: @PedroSánchezTerraf, I see your point about subalgebras. As for quotient algebras, your comment is mistaken. The statement "there are at least $3$ elements" is not an existentially-quantified equation.

Comment: Right there, I missed the "equations".